# Representing directional data from an attribute field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, direction

I have a table in ArcMap 10.2 containing strike measurements, in degrees, for ~100 sample sites. Each measurement has a UTM tied to it, and the map has already been populated with points, but I would like to have those points serve as directional representations (arrows would be great).

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want your points to show the direction from an existing attribute?  You can symbolise your points with an arrow or similar, and set Rotation to your direction field from the layer Symbology tab (from the Advanced dropdown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured this out with some fiddling. Here's how to do this:

1. Open "properties" for the layer in question
2. Navigate to the "Symbology" tab
3. When classifying data by quantity, click the "Advanced" drop-down menu under the symbol window
4. Click "Rotation"
5. Choose the attribute field with your directional data, and select your rotation style (geographic in my case)
6. In the "symbol selector" window, click "Edit Symbol..."
7. under "type", select an Arrow type marker, and adjust the dimensions to suit your purpose
8. As my data was in degrees off of north, I made sure the arrows starting position was vertical. This required me to set the initial angle to 90 degrees